# Undefined Index PHP, MySQL, PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, phpmyadmin, undefined

**Error:**

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: VIN in C:\wamp\www\php\myJoyofPHP\viewcar.php on line 10

```
09 <?php include 'db.php';  
10 $vin = $_GET['VIN'];
11 $query = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY";
12 /* Try to query the database */
13 if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
14 //Don't do anything if successful.
15 }
16 else
17 {
18 echo "Sorry, a vehicle with VIN of $vin cannot be found ".mysql_error()."<br>";
19 }
20  
21 //Loop through all the rows returned by the query, creating a table row for each
22 while ($result_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
23  $year = $result_ar['YEAR'];
24  $make = $result_ar['Make'];
25  $model = $result_ar['Model'];
26  $trim = $result_ar['TRIM'];
27  $color = $result_ar['EXT_COLOR'];
28  $interior = $result_ar['INT_COLOR'];
29  $mileage = $result_ar['MILEAGE'];
30  $transmission = $result_ar['TRANSMISSION'];
31  $price = $result_ar['ASKING_PRICE'];
32 }
33 echo "$year $make $model </p>";
34 echo "<p>Asking Price: $price </p>";
35 echo "<p>Exterior Color: $color </p>";
36 echo "<p>Interior Color: $interior </p>";
37
38 $mysqli->close();
39 ?>
```

I'm not concerned about security at the moment because I am just learning the basics as of now. So please don't respond saying that it's vulnerable code, I know.

I have a Column named 'VIN' in the 'cars' database within PhpMyAdmin with multiple values in it but For some reason this error comes up. Also, underneath the error, a single data set appears.

Why would I be getting this error?
Why would I be getting the error especially if a database exists with the same column name 'VIN'?
When I enter the following code above it, there is a variable error too.

```
$value = isset($array['VIN']) ? $array['VIN'] : '';
$value = array_key_exists('VIN', $array) ? $array['VIN'] : '';
```

Also, this is the db.php file that is included:

```
<?php 
//localhost, root, password, database
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','cars');
/*check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
//select a database to work with
$mysqli->select_db("cars");

?>
```

As I mentioned, I understand this is a vulnerable database. There is no password. Please don't post anything regarding that, as I need to fully understand the basics. Thank you.

Comment: vin is undefined then define it....

Comment: `mysql_error` is not the correct thing to use here, it's from the wrong family of functions. Try and stick to the `mysqli` object-oriented interface exclusively to avoid slips like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code and notice message will disappear, its just a notice saying that $vin is not defined because sometimes $vin is empty, it does not get any value from $_GET

```
if (isset($_GET['VIN']))
{
   $vin = $_GET['VIN'];
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work, but when I enter
        `$query = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE VIN='$vin'";`
on the line below it, another Notice comes up saying 
**( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: vin in C:\wamp\www\php\myJoyofPHP\viewcar.php on line 14**

If the vin variable was written directly above this line, why would it say it is missing?

Comment: if $vin is not defined you cannot use select * from inventory where VIN='$vin', either you have to change the query or you can assign blank to $vin

Comment: please check in url whether Vin variable is available or not

Answer (score 1):

First, is not an "error", it is a "notice". You can ignore it almost all the time.
Its mean 'VIN' index is not defined inside the $_GET global var/array. 
That is 'VIN' do not come in the url parameters.
PHP assumes it like an empty string.

Maybe the best solution is some like:

```
if( isset($_GET['VIN']) && $_GET['VIN'] != "" ){ // you can add others validations like string lenght or regex
  $vin = $_GET['VIN'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY";
  //...all your code...
}else{
  // Do something when no VIN comes in the url
}
```

Obviously you need to use your script with de VIN parameter:
.....viewcar.php?VIN=ABC123

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing you to receive that warning `$vin = $_GET['VIN'];` which means that you are not receiving `VIN` in the request, you need to check it as

```
if (isset($_GET['VIN'])) {
 //rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple:

```
$vin = @$_GET['VIN'];
```

If `VIN` was not fed in

- There will be no error message;
- `$vin` will be `NULL`.
- Later, you can use `if (isset($vin)) ...`, which reads easily.